# How to use multiple columns but only one column in GROUP BY and ORDER BY

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2

I want to display multiple columns from the join table, but only use one column to `group by` and `order by`

[image]

My PostgreSQL query is like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (r.id_rekrutmen)
       r.id_rekrutmen,
       r.judul_rekrutmen,
       rw.tanggal_rekrutmen
FROM rekrutmen r
   INNER JOIN rekrutmen_waktu rw
      ON r.id_rekrutmen = rw.id_rekrutmen
ORDER BY r.id_rekrutmen, rw.tanggal_rekrutmen DESC;
```

Comment: The query looks OK; what is your question?

Comment: I can not display like the example image that I want using that query,,

Comment: Do you mean `... ORDER BY r.id_rekrutmen DESC, rw.tanggal_rekrutmen DESC;` ?

Comment: I want "ORDER BY tanggal_rekrutmen DESC"

Comment: so what is the issue if you do `ORDER BY rw.tanggal_rekrutmen DESC`

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.1 and 9.2 are [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT 
           r.id_rekrutmen,
           r.judul_rekrutmen,
           MAX(rw.tanggal_rekrutmen) AS tanggal_rekrutmen
    FROM rekrutmen r
       INNER JOIN rekrutmen_waktu rw
          ON r.id_rekrutmen = rw.id_rekrutmen
    GROUP BY 
           r.id_rekrutmen,
           r.judul_rekrutmen,
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this work with me,,


SELECT r.id_rekrutmen, r.judul_rekrutmen, MAX(rw.tanggal_rekrutmen) AS tanggal_rekrutmen FROM rekrutmen r INNER JOIN rekrutmen_waktu rw ON r.id_rekrutmen = rw.id_rekrutmen GROUP BY r.id_rekrutmen, r.judul_rekrutmen ORDER BY tanggal_rekrutmen DESC